# Best way to send and process variable sized data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

On this page...

http://lab.2toria.com/reflex/index2.php

When the user has dragged and dropped blocks onto the grid, I want to be able to send the positions in some form to a php script that will save them into a table that simply records the coordinates (eg "x1y2", "x1y3", etc) into rows.  The fields in my table so far are VERY simple (blockID, blockCoords)

What would be the best way to do this?  I'm after your opinion on two things:-

1)  Using jQuery ajax, how could I send a string containing the coordinates as a list?  Would it be best to create an xml string, or is there another way I've not thought of...and how would I do this

and..

2)  Based on the method used to send the data (xml, or whatever), how would I then process the data in the receiving php script to save the data into a table.  I know how to save records etc, just wanting to know how best to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('element').droppable({
    drop:function(event, ui){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/my/file.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'left' : ui.helper.position().left,
                   'top': ui.helper.position().top},
            success: function(data){
              //do something with the response from the server
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And in `/path/to/my/file.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['left'])):
    $db = new mysqli('connection info here');
    $q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO some_table (left, top) VALUES (?,?)'); //prepare the statement
    $q->bind_param('ss', $_POST['left'], $_POST['top']); //safe binding
    if(FALSE !== $q->execute()):
        return 'Query Executed!';
    endif; //execute the statement
    return false;
endif;
```

So in the php file we're simply checking for the existence of the `$_POST` variable `left`. We assume top will be available also. We make a mysqli connection, prepare a safe statement, bind the parameters as `strings`, using the `$_POST` left/topvalues. Then we check if the execution didn't return false (returns true/false), and if it didn't, we pass a value and exit out of the conditionals all together. If not, the return false will fire by default.

**Edit**

From your comment, you want to save the actions that the user performs until ready to actually perform the insert, that's easily doable as well.

```
var dc = 0,
    drops = {};
```

`dc` will be the `dropcount`, and `drops` will be an object.

```
$('element').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){
        drops[dc] = {'left' : ui.helper.position().left, 'top' : ui.helper.position().top};
        dc++;
    }
});
```

In the above, we simply increment through the `drops` object, storing the information for the left/top values on each drop.

```
$('.save').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'drops': drops},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);  
        }
    });
});
```

Here, we have a save button with a class of save, we prevent the default action, then we sent the drops object to the server.

```
if(isset($_POST['drops'])):
    //same process as outlined above, use a helper function to insert the rows
endif;
```

Now we check for the existence of the $_POST variable 'drops', we'll employ the same tactics as above. I would simply recommend a helper `function saveDrops($obj)`, iterating the returned drops and performing a save for each obj passed in.

Comment: This seems to 'save as you go', which is great (and I hadn't thought of that, so thanks..), but how would I do it if I wanted to send all coordinates as one file and then process??

Comment: @Mat Richardson so you're saying that you want to hold the coordinates in an object in javascript, then when the user performs some 'final' action, we'll actually do the insert?

Comment: Yep, when the user clicks the 'save level' button I'd like the page to generate a list (or something) of the coordinates of the blocks placed, and then send them to the php script for saving as a job lot..

Comment: Looks great..  Can't test right now, so will get back to you tomorrow.  Thanks ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

1) Yep, use jQuery ajax posting the coords and block id.

2) They will be available to php in the $_POST variable.

See:[jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: What would be the best way to post the coordinates?  eg, if I wanted to send coordinates x1y1, x2y2, etc - what would be the best way to do this?  If as an xml file, for example, how?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy's answer is bloody fantastic.